# Adding string to vector<const char *> is giving weird behavior with strtok()

Tags: c++, file-io, vector, strtok

I'm trying to add the strings returned from strtok to a vector, but for some reason it only adds the last string that was in the file...

**Code:**

```
// read the remaining lines
// put address and ports into ipaddr and ports, respectively
for (unsigned i = 0; i < numStones; ++i) {
    const char * item;
    fgets(buffer, 255, fp);
    //printf("%s", buffer);
    item = strtok(buffer, " ");
    printf("%s\n", item);
    ipaddr.push_back(item);
    item = strtok(NULL, "\n"); 
    printf("%s\n", item);
    ports.push_back(item);
}
#ifdef _DEBUG
for (unsigned i = 0; i < numStones; i++) {
    printf("IP Address %d: %s\n", i, ipaddr.at(i));
    printf("Port %d: %s\n", i, ports.at(i));
}
#endif
```

**Output:**

```
129.82.47.21
3360
129.82.47.22
5540
129.82.47.23
7732
129.82.47.24
8896
IP Address 0: 129.82.47.24
Port 0: 8896
IP Address 1: 129.82.47.24
Port 1: 8896
IP Address 2: 129.82.47.24
Port 2: 8896
IP Address 3: 129.82.47.24
Port 3: 8896
```

As you can see, the code is getting the right string from the tokenizer, but not pushing the right string to the vector. This is driving me nuts, help and thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're pushing pointers without allocating new memory.  You're always supplying a pointer to some position within your buffer.

In C you would use `strdup` to copy the string.

In C++ you would normally construct a `std::string` and store those in your vector instead of `char *`.  However, you may have your own memory management scheme with a buffer of strings stored somewhere.  Or you could use `strdup` if you want.

I generally agree with Jonathan Potter's comment on another answer:

> Storing pointers in vectors should be discouraged

If you are new to programming, you should take that advice 100%.  When you are more advanced, there are times when putting pointers in a vector is totally legit.

---

**[edit]** Clarification.

The quick fix is this (yes, we should normally check that `strdup` didn't return `NULL`):

```
ports.push_back(strdup(item));
```

But that makes a cleanup job, because when you're finished with the vector, you have all these pointers that need to be freed:

```
for( int i = 0; i < ports.size(); i++ ) free(ports[i]);
```

The better fix is to use `std::vector<std::string>` as your datatype, which will handle the memory for you.

Comment: Yes, thanks for *pointing* that out (apologies for the lame pun). I was hoping to store C strings in the vector because I'm going to have to buffer and send them through a socket at some point. But I think I'll just go with a vector of strings and call c_str() as needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you pushed into the vector is a pointer.So after `for`, the vector store the same memory position `numStones` times.If you want to save the true information, `new` a memory block to save it, and then push it into vector.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. Mainly these comments helped me. You have to create a `char*` auxiliary variable and make it new everytime you read a new string so the address would be a new one everytime. And after that you just `push_back`.
like

`char* aux = new char[100];
 strcpy(aux, your_str);
 vector.push_back(aux);`